# Quartz.net high availability?

Tags: sql-server, quartz.net, high-availability

I am looking to implement an instance of Quartz.net, probably as a windows service. We plan to use SQL server as the back end storage of job data.

Long story short, high availability is paramount in our project. The quartz.net site talks about load balancing, but is a little lite on details. Does anyone know of some good methods to provide high availability to a Quartz.net implementation like this?

Suggestions or links to articles would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this book, it's about Quartz (not Quartz .NET i think, but many of the features are similar):
**Quartz Job Scheduling Framework: Building Open Source Enterprise Applications**

There is a chapter about clustering, it might be of help regarding your issue.